# How to exclude META-INF files from bundle?

Tags: java, maven, apache-felix

How can I exclude some META-INF files when building a bundled jar using the maven apache felix plugin?

Here's my felix config

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>          
      <instructions>
       <!-- Embed all dependencies -->
       <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive> 
       <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
     </instructions>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I'm pulling in all transitive dependencies and embedding them because I want to create a single jar that I can add to my classpath.

When I try to run my jar though I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

Following a post I found on SO, I manually deleted some META-INF/ files that appear to come from the bouncy files. I then recreated my jar file and it worked. Is there a way to do this automatically using the felix plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shade plugin makes this easy. So I switched to using the shade plugin rather than using the felix plugin. Here's my pom plugin config:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <!-- We need to exclude the signatures for any signed jars otherwise
                   we get an exception. -->
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

See http://goo.gl/dbwiiJ