# How do I exclude extraDependency META-INF files for exec-war goal?

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

My question is exactly the problem faced by this user of maven-shade plugin:

[How to exclude META-INF files from bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292874/how-to-exclude-meta-inf-files-from-bundle)

But I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin to build a self-running webapp. I have recently switched database drivers to use Microsoft's own driver which implements JDBC4. Now I have problems including it as an extraDependency in my exec-war goal. Here is the relevant part of the `pom.xml`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <path>/oases</path>
                <contextFile>applicationContext.xml</contextFile>
                <extraDependencies>
                    <extraDependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0</version>
                    </extraDependency>
                </extraDependencies>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The project builds fine except that maven does not obey the `exclude`directive so that the sqljdbc4 RSA file is included in the META-INF directory. This means that when I try to run my exec-war jar file I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid 
    signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

I have read the code and as far as I can tell the plugin is correctly configured to exclude the sqljdbc4 META-INF files. Here is the plugin code for version 2.2, which is what I am using. It looks like this should do what I want. However, the exec-war jar still includes `META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA`

#### org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractExecWarMojo.java

```java
protected void extractJarToArchive( JarFile file, ArchiveOutputStream os, String[] excludes )
    throws IOException
    {
        Enumeration<? extends JarEntry> entries = file.entries();
        while ( entries.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            JarEntry j = entries.nextElement();
            if ( excludes != null && excludes.length > 0 )
            {
                for ( String exclude : excludes )
                {
                    if ( SelectorUtils.match( exclude, j.getName() ) )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase( j.getName(), "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" ) )
            {
                continue;
            }
            os.putArchiveEntry( new JarArchiveEntry( j.getName() ) );
            IOUtils.copy( file.getInputStream( j ), os );
            os.closeArchiveEntry();
        }
        if ( file != null )
        {
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDITS**

1. Reverted to plugin version 2.1 due to the version 2.2 bug noted in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436438/980454
2. One workaround is to [create an unsigned version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757083) of the dependency jar.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted for `AbstractExecWarMojo` has a bug: the `continue` in the inner for loop has no effect whatsoever.  Instead, It should be continuing on the outer while loop in order to skip placing archive entries whenever an `exclude` is matched, as follows:

```
protected void extractJarToArchive( JarFile file, ArchiveOutputStream os, String[] excludes )
    throws IOException
    {
        Enumeration<? extends JarEntry> entries = file.entries();
        outer:
        while ( entries.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            JarEntry j = entries.nextElement();
            if ( excludes != null && excludes.length > 0 )
            {
                for ( String exclude : excludes )
                {
                    if ( SelectorUtils.match( exclude, j.getName() ) )
                    {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase( j.getName(), "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" ) )
            {
                continue;
            }
            os.putArchiveEntry( new JarArchiveEntry( j.getName() ) );
            IOUtils.copy( file.getInputStream( j ), os );
            os.closeArchiveEntry();
        }
        if ( file != null )
        {
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

To fix this problem in your project, you can checkout/modify/build the tomcat7-maven-plugin from source.  If you do so, and you test it out successfully, it would be great if you contributed a patch.  I already filed an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-300) for it.